# modal box does not appear when clicking on <a> element

Tags: jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I am building a website based on "fullpage.js" and I have some slides. For every slide there is an info button made with an  **"a"** element with a glyphicon from bootstrap. When the info button is clicked I want a **modal box** with the id of **modal1** to appear by toggling "**.closed**" from **display:none** to **display:block**.

The problem I have is that the modal does not appear, I tried to add **console.log** to the function but when the button is clicked nothing happens. I am using **jQuery** in my case but if you have a better method it would be more than welcome.

I removed parts of the website that I thought were irrelevant to the question.

Here is the link to the actual website: [click here](http://79.170.40.40/ashrafsalem.com/#firstPage)

**This is my code :**

**HTML & Javascript**

```
<head>
    <!--jQuery-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--    Bootstrap-->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!--Google fonts-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Prompt|Text+Me+One|Quicksand|Monoton" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--Fullpage.js-->
    <script src="Fullpage-js/fullPage.js-master/vendors/jquery.easings.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Fullpage-js/jquery.fullPage.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Fullpage-js/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
    <!--CSS file-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <!--particles.js-->
    <script src="particles.js-master/particles.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'particles.js-master/particlesjs-config.json', function () {
            console.log('callback - particles.js config loaded');
        });
    </script>
    <!--Fullpage setup-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#fullpage').fullpage({
                sectionsColor: ['rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)', 'rgba(105, 163, 193, 0.63)', 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)', '#f1937a', ],
                anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', 'thirdPage', 'fourthPage', ],
                //                    navigation: true,
                slidesNavigation: true,
                continuousVertical: true,
                verticalCentered: true,
                touchSensitivity: 5,
                css3:true,
                easingcss3: "ease-in-out",
                recordHistory: false,
                //                scrollBar:true
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>  
<body>


        <div class="section first">
        </div>
        <!--SECTION 2-->
        <div class="section">
        </div>
        <!--SECTION 3-->
        <div class="section">
            <div class="slide">
                <div class="slideContainer">
                        <h1>text</h1> 
                        <!--Buttons-->


    <!--This div contains the two buttons-->
                        <div class="buttonContainer">

    <!--This one should trigger the modal box-->
                            <a class="info" id="button1">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>                           
                            </a>

    <!--Another button-->
                            <a href="" class="info">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>

                <!--This is the modal div-->    
                        <div class="modal" id="modal1">
                            <div>
                                <p>bla bla bla</p>
                                <a href="#close" title="Close" id="close">X</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

    <!--modal overlay-->
                        <div class="modal-overlay" id="modal-overlay">
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>

<!--Other slides-->
            <div class="slide">
            <div class="slide">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--SECTION 4-->
        <div class="section">
        </div>
    </div>


    <!--GENERAL JAVASCRIPT-->
    <script type="text/javascript">

        //The code that should trigger the modal

        var modal = document.querySelector("#modal1");
        var modalOverlay = document.querySelector("#modal-overlay");
        var closeButton = document.querySelector("#close");
        var openButton = document.querySelector("#button1");

        closeButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
            console.log("it works");
          modal.classList.toggle("closed");
          modalOverlay.classList.toggle("closed");
        });

        openButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
          modal.classList.toggle("closed");
          modalOverlay.classList.toggle("closed");
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
/*colors used: 
Blue:#69a3c1
Orange:#f1937a
*/

.section {
    margin-top: 0;
}
.particles {
    height: 100vh !important;
    width: 100vw !important;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 0;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "adam" !important;
}
.first {
    z-index: 1;
}
#fp-nav ul li a span,
.fp-slidesNav ul li a span {} #fp-nav ul li a.active span,
.fp-slidesNav ul li a.active span,
#fp-nav ul li:hover a.active span,
.fp-slidesNav ul li:hover a.active span {} .fp-prev {
    margin-left: 3vw;
}
.slideContainer h1 {
    font-family: 'Text Me One', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: black;
    font-size: 5vw;
}
.slideContainer {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50vw;
    text-align: center;
}
.slideContainer img {
    width: 20vw;
}
.fp-controlArrow.fp-prev {
    border: none;
    width: 70px;
    height: 105px;
    margin-left: -15px;
    background-image: url(../images/left-arrow.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 50px 50px;
    background-color: rgba(241, 147, 122, 0.4);
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s;
}
.fp-controlArrow.fp-prev:hover {
    background-color: rgba(241, 147, 122, 0.7);
}
.fp-controlArrow.fp-next {
    border: none;
    width: 70px;
    height: 105px;
    margin-right: -15px;
    background-image: url(../images/right-arrow.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 50px 50px;
    background-color: rgba(241, 147, 122, 0.4);
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s;
}
.fp-controlArrow.fp-next:hover {
    background-color: rgba(241, 147, 122, 0.7);
}
.info {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
.info div {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background-color: aqua;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.slideContainer h1 {
    font-family: 'Monoton', cursive;
    font-size: 9vw;
    color: #69a3c1;
    white-space: pre;
    margin-bottom: 8vh;
}
.slideContainer {
    width: 100vw;
}
.buttonContainer {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.buttonContainer span {
    font-size: 4vw;
    border-radius: 100px;
    border: 0;
    color: #69a3c1;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.2s;
}
.buttonContainer span:hover {
    color: #f1937a;
    cursor: pointer;
    a
}
.modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 600px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    max-height: 100%;
    z-index: 1010;
}
.modal-overlay {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /* for example... */

    display: block;
}
.modal.closed {
    display: none;
}
```

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at your site, the modal button works and triggers the click event. However I found two issues:

1. Toggle class `.closed`

   The bootstrap classes for toggling modals is `.modal-open`. You're doing it the opposite way round, which is fine, however you need to change the css for `.modal` to `display: block` by default. It's now set to `display: none;` (from bootstrap), so your toggle class changes nothing.
2. Modal positioning

   Your modal positioning is way off. After changing the css bug mentioned in point (1), your modal appears, just way off screen so you'll never see it. Fixing the position then displays it as you intended.

Comment: I added the display:block to .modal, but I see the modal in the center as soon as the page loads and the close button works, But when I click on the modal (info) button the modal does not show again. Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: it works for me. your modal is appearing on the first slide instead of the slide where the modal info button is, which is why you're not seeing it. you'll need to fix the positioning.

Comment: It works! I think the problem was that the #modal-overlay didn't disappear with the modal box so I couldn't click on the info button to make it appear. I also changed position:fixed with position:absolute to .modal so it remains inside the slide.